# Remap the "select all" shortcut in Windows and Office

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Most of you will not be aware that Microsoft, since 1990s, had a very bad idea: in Italian-language products the "select all" shortcut is NOT CTRL+A

The chose the awkard keyboard shortcut CTRL+"digit 5 from the keypad"!!!!
This is EXTREMELY annoying, as is NOT possible to do this with a single-hand!
And then, of course, ALL of non-microsoft software is ctrl-a, so it is very frustrating
And also, what to do with laptops?
CTRL+FN+numpad+I?
WEIRD!

my workaround is using english windows+italian MUI, but i would prefer a "real fix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

control and 5? The what?

```
#IfWinActive, [ms office window title goes here]
^a::^NumPad5
#IfWinActive
```

In the AutoHotKey scripting language would fix that :)

Comment: unfortunately, in Office, Microsoft has remapped CTRL+E to CTRL+A, if i do a double remap it would work?
Maybe the Italian localization team thought it was funny to remap lots of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: The syntax is [hotkey]::[result], ^ is control, ! is alt, + is shift, and # is the windows key. You should be able to remap whatever to whatever, hopefully! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Ever wanted to quickly and easily
>   define your own keyboard layout for a
>   language Microsoft doesn't support? Or
>   define your own keyboard layout so you
>   can quickly and easily enter your
>   favorite symbols with a simple
>   keystroke?

Voilá, **[The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)**